# Collect and sum statistics of `strace` commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operating-system, sh

I know that I can run`strace -c ls` to collect system call statistics on the `ls` executable. However, I want to run the command `strace -c {some executable here}` mulitiple times over different executables, merge the individual results, and then write to a single file.

I want to merge the 'syscall' and the 'calls' columns. So for example, if `ls` makes 19 `mmap` system calls and `tr` makes 11 `mmap` system calls, I would like to merge those results so that the final statistics simply show 30 `mmap` system calls overall in some file. Moreover, if a system call only appears in one executable, it should still be included in the final results.

How can I do that?

Comment: google for redirect output to file (append)

Comment: Please specify which columns from `strace -c` should be merged, (or *added*, presumably).

Comment: Yes Drako, you are right. Redirecting output to file is not the main issue. It is merging the statistics of the `strace -c {some exectuable here}` commands that I am struggling with. I just included that for completeness.

Comment: what kind of merging? what is your preferred output?

Comment: @agc. I want to merge the 'syscall' and the 'calls' columns. So for example, if  `ls` makes 19 `mmap` system calls and `tr` makes 11 `mmap` system calls, I would like to merge those results so that the final statistics simply show 30 `mmap` system calls overall in some file. Moreover, if a system call only appears in one executable, it should still be included in the final results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` to find *mmap* calls, which are then piped to [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) (on *Debian* variants, install with`apt install datamash`) to group by column 5, (i.e. *mmap*), and sum column 4:

```
for f in /bin/ls /bin/tr ; do strace -c $f 2>&1 ; done |  
    grep mmap | datamash -W -g5 sum 4
```

Output:

```
mmap    29
```

---

1. Example showing what similar data looked like *before* it was
   summed:

   ```
   for f in /bin/false /bin/true ; do strace -c $f 2>&1 ; done |  
        grep mmap | tee /tmp/old | datamash -W -g5 sum 4 ; echo --- ; cat /tmp/old

   mmap    12
   ---
     0.00    0.000000           0         6           mmap
     0.00    0.000000           0         6           mmap
   ```
2. The `-s` switch lets `datamash` group, sort, and separately sum
   *all* the syscalls:

   ```
   for f in /bin/pwd  /bin/false /bin/true ; do
        strace -c $f 2>&1 > /dev/null |
            grep -v ':' | cut --complement -c 42-50 |
            sed '1s/^% /%_/;2d' | head -n -2 ;  
   done | sed -n '1p;/^%/d;p' | datamash -HW -sg5 sum 4  | 
          xargs printf "%-12s\t%14s\n"
   ```

   (Note that the `strace` output needs cleaning, which is done by
   `cut`, `sed`, *et al*...)

   Output:

   ```
   GroupBy(syscall)        sum(calls)
   access                       9
   arch_prctl                   3
   brk                          5
   close                       23
   execve                       3
   fstat                       22
   getcwd                       1
   ioctl                        1
   mmap                        31
   mprotect                    12
   munmap                       3
   open                        34
   read                         5
   write                        1
   ```

Comment: Thanks @agc. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strace -o <filename>` option to save the output into file, and then use the files to make `diff`.

Pass time parameter to the filename with `strace -o "filename-$(date +%T)"`

Concatenating files with `cat file1 file2 > file3`

Redirect output to a file with `> filename`